# Analyzing Betting (Keno) in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, histograms

Keno is a popular lottery game that is available with all of the larger casino softwares. The player is given a ticket with 70 numbers on it. He picks 1 to 11 numbers on the ticket. 20 winning numbers are selected randomly. The more of the player's picks that are selected, the bigger the payout.

In Sweden, my home country, *Svenska Spel* (a state owned company) offers the following 
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
\text{Number of Correct Guesses}&\text{Return} &\text{Average Chance of Winning} \\ \hline 
11 & 5000000 &\text{See below} \\ \hline 10 &125000 & \\ \hline9 & 3000 & \\ \hline8 & 300 & \\ \hline 7 & 30 & \\ \hline 6 & 10 & \\ \hline 5 & 5 & \\ \hline 4 & 0 & \\ \hline 3 & 0 & \\ \hline 2  &0 & \\ \hline 1 & 0 & \\ \hline 0 & 0 & \text{1 to 6.2} 
\end{array}

> What I would like to do is to calculate the probability to obtain $0,1,2,\dots, 11$ right guesses on Keno 11 and compare it to *Svenska spel*. In addition, I would like to plot this result using histograms.

**My Take**

What I have done is to define the hypergeometric probability distribution function as:

```
    Urn[good_, bad_, draws_, need_] := ({{good},{need}}) ({{bad},{draws - need}})/
({{good + bad},{draws}})
```

I have then used this to calculate the KenoOdds using the following code:

```
 KenoOdds = 
 Table[MatrixForm[
   Table[{g, k, Round[1/N[Urn[g, 70, 20, k]]] - 1}, {k, 0, g}]], {g, 
   4, 11}]
```

The problem is that the first code does not work; all I receive is this message "An unknown box name (Hold) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression." H

Comment: Hmm... seems to work here. I do get some divide by zero messages, but those are unrelated to your question. It seems like some hidden/invisible characters might have crept in to your cell. Try deleting it and copy-pasting what you have written here. Remember to clear definitions or start a fresh kernel.

Comment: You are inputting column matrices when you are likely looking for `Binomial`.  Please look it up in the docs.  You need to provide precise and correct syntax for computers to understand ...

Comment: Haha, is this the first lab in Probability theory I, at Stockholm Uni?

Answer (score 4):

You probably input something that looks like
$$
\frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{good} \\
 \text{need} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{bad} \\
 \text{draws}-\text{need} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{bad}+\text{good} \\
 \text{draws} \\
\end{array}
\right)}
$$

These however were not interpreted as binomial coefficients, but as column vectors (2 by 1 matrices).  You can see this from the form of the expression you pasted here.

You are likely looking for

```
(Binomial[good, need] Binomial[bad, draws - need])/Binomial[good + bad, draws]
```

Mathematica does allow you to input something that looks like [traditional mathematical notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html) and it can interpret some of it, but this is not reliable.  Your case is a perfect example of why.  Mathematica does in fact give a warning before evaluating a `TraditionalForm` input.  Generally, `TraditionalForm` is more useful for reading output than for inputting new expressions.

Answer (score 2):

monte carlo approach..

```
n = 1000000;
nchoice = 11;
nball = 70;
draws = 20;
{#[[1]], N[ #[[2]]/n]} & /@ Sort@Tally@Table[
         Length@Intersection[
                 RandomSample[Range[nball], nchoice],
                 RandomSample[Range[nball], draws]
                            ], {n}]
```

Compare with Szabolcs' formula (which is just a tad faster.. )

```
   0, 0.017371 0.0172627
   1, 0.094738 0.0949448
   2, 0.219235 0.219994
   3, 0.283973 0.282849
   4, 0.223563 0.223648
   5, 0.113827 0.113857
   6, 0.037821 0.0379524
   7, 0.008278 0.00825053
   8, 0.001096  0.00114103
   9, 0.00009 0.0000950859
   10, 8.*10^-6 4.26916*10^-6
   11  ---       7.76212*10^-8
```